# Can't connect to github on terminal. Error message: Proxy CONNECT aborted on

Tags: github, proxy, terminal, cocoapods

I'm trying to load AFNetworking library on my project but in terminal I have always this error message:

```
MacBook-Pro-Aleksandr:KAFileMap aleksandrkarpov$ pod install

Analyzing dependencies

Downloading dependencies

Installing AFNetworking (2.5.2)

[!] Error installing AFNetworking

[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git 
/Users/aleksandrkarpov/Desktop/KAFileMap/Pods/AFNetworking --single-branch --
depth 1 --branch 2.5.2

Cloning into '/Users/aleksandrkarpov/Desktop/KAFileMap/Pods/AFNetworking'...

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': 
Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

Anybody can help me? Thank's

Answer (score 0):

GitHub is [currently suffering from a distributed denial of service attack](https://status.github.com/messages). Try again later.